# Regular Expressions code in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to skip the url which contains any office file format or pdf at the end of url here is my code.

```
String Url ="http://chemistry.csudh.edu/faculty/jim/aromaticity.ppt";

        if (!Url.matches(".*(doc|dot|docx|docm|dotx|dotm)")
                || !Url.matches(".*ppt|pot|pps")
                || !Url.matches(".*xls|xlt|xlm")
                || !Url.matches(".*pdf"))
            System.out.print(Url);
        else
            System.out.print("true");
```

I want to know what is wrong with this code fragment as it prints url every time but i want to skip the url which contain any of above format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the parenthesis in the second and third regex. `!Url.matches(".*ppt|pot|pps")` will match all the URLs that doesn't end with `ppt`, but the URL like `abc.pot` will not be matched by that regex, and the condition will be `true`. you should change it to:

```
!Url.matches(".*(ppt|pot|pps)")
```

.. as in the first regex. Also, that should be `&&` instead of `||` in your condition.

BTW, why do you have 4 different `matches()` invocation? That will have to compile 4 different regexes, while you could have done it with a single regex. just add all the extensions to the first regex list:

```
if (!url.matches(".*(doc|dot|docx|docm|dotx|dotm|ppt|pot|pps|xls|xlt|xlm|pdf)")
```

*P.S:* Kindly follow Java Naming Conventions. Variable names should start with lower-case alphabets.

Comment: thanks it worked, and i have change it to single regex i didn't realized that it will have to compile 4 different regexes.

Answer (score 1):

It's a `logic` error, you should change it to

```
String Url ="http://chemistry.csudh.edu/faculty/jim/aromaticity.ppt";

    if (!Url.matches(".*(doc|dot|docx|docm|dotx|dotm)")
            && !Url.matches(".*ppt|pot|pps")
            && !Url.matches(".*xls|xlt|xlm")
            && !Url.matches(".*pdf"))
        System.out.print(Url);
    else
        System.out.print("true");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition if faulty, since you're using `||` instead of `&&`. Consider the following - a URL that ends in `.pdf` cannot end in `.doc`, and vice versa - so the condition will **always** evaluate to `true`. Logically, you want to test that a URL does not match **any** document format - with infers using `&&`:

```
String Url ="http://chemistry.csudh.edu/faculty/jim/aromaticity.ppt";

if (!Url.matches(".*(doc|dot|docx|docm|dotx|dotm)")
        && !Url.matches(".*ppt|pot|pps")
        && !Url.matches(".*xls|xlt|xlm")
        && !Url.matches(".*pdf"))
    System.out.print(Url);
else {
    System.out.print("true");
}
```